# How to translate "pushl 2000" from AT&T asm to Intel syntax on i386

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, att, i386

I'm trying to translate the following from AT&T assembly to Intel assembly:

```
pushl 2000
```

Now this compiles down to:

```
ff 35 d0 07 00 00       pushl  0x7d0
```

But no matter what I try, I cannot get the same in Intel synax, I've tried:

```
intel asm
disassembly after compiling to at&t

push 2000
68 d0 07 00 00          push   $0x7d0

push [2000]
68 d0 07 00 00          push   $0x7d0

push dword ptr [2000]
68 d0 07 00 00          push   $0x7d0

push dword ptr 2000
68 d0 07 00 00          push   $0x7d0
```

So I'm out of clues, what is the equivalent of "pushl 2000"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the original code isn't doing what you think it's doing.  According to msdev the disassembly is:

```
003AFCFC FF 35 D0 07 00 00 push        dword ptr ds:[7D0h]
```

Which is equal to pushing:

```
*((DWORD*)2000)
```

NOT pushing the value 2000 onto the stack.  However - if that's really what you want then the instruction is:

```
push dword ptr ds:[2000]
```

`ds:` is an indication to use the `ds` segment register.  The segment registers are a hold-over from nasty 16-bit days.  The major ones are `cs` - code segment, `ds` - data segment and `ss` - stack segment (and `fs` which is where thread locals are stored).  Think of them as base offsets into memory.  By default data accesses are off the `ds` segment.

My guess as to why `push dword ptr [2000]` didn't work is that the compiler realized that that was a silly thing for you to use and 'fixed it'.  By forcing use of the `ds` prefix you indicate that you really mean to do a memory access there.

Comment: That does indeed seems to be the correct translation. 

I can't say I understand the original code very well (nor do I really desire to), but I want to translate it to Intel syntax.

Can you explain where the "ds:" is coming from?

Comment: Okay - I added a little description of the `ds` to the answer.

Comment: Do you happen to know how I can get as to not try to be clever like that?

Comment: Sorry - nope.  My guess is that an long time ago someone made a bug in the compiler and it became a defacto standard.

Answer (score 1):

for me, in GNU assembler 2.18, for 32-bit target

```
.intel_syntax
push dword [2000]
```

generates :

```
0:   ff 35 d0 07 00 00       pushl  0x7d0
```

and for nasm :

```
push dword [dword 2000]
```

Comment: That same code generates this for me "   0: 68 d4 07 00 00        push   $0x7d4" on as 2.20 passing it --32.